# How to make dynamic paint brushes to affect some canvases, and not to affect others?

Tags: particles, weight-painting, dynamic-paint, vertex-paint

The Sphere is moving and draws dynamic paint on the Cube.
The Cube emits particles that draw dynamic paint on the Plane.

[image]

- How to make the particles (emitted by the cube), not to draw dynamic
  paint on the cube itself?
- How to make the Sphere not to draw dinamic paint on the Plane?